# can not assignment mutations in Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

a strange problem that "val" and "ok" can be "console.log()",but state.user can not be assignment anything.
Well, state.user also can print 'ok' on the website

```
export const state = () => ({
  user: 'ok'
})
export const mutations = {
  setUser (state, val) {
    console.log(val, 'ok')
    state.user = val
  }
}

export const actions = {
  setUser: ({ commit }, user) => {
    commit('setUser', user)
  }
}
computed: {
    ...mapState({ user: state => state.user })
  }
```

what should I do, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your state is function that always returns same user. It should be object.

Comment: like this？```const state = () => ({ user: Object})```,well it does not work

Comment: Like this: `const state = { user: 'ok' }`